# How can I dynamically show values in a PropertyPaneDropdown in spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to show a lists titles in the select tutorials field. But list title values not showing on the first click.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP SPFx property pane control for it.

please find the below link for details and description is

[PropertyFieldListPicker control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldListPicker.html)

Comment: I want to values from a particular list in the dropdown. but PropertyFieldListPicker control is used for selecting lists.